# How do you port QUrl addQueryItem to Qt5's QUrlQuery?

Tags: qt, qt5, qurl

In `Qt` 4, the following code using `QUrl` works:

```
QUrl u;
foreach (const settings::PostItem & pi, settings.post)
    u.addQueryItem(pi.name, pi.value);
postData = u.encodedQuery();
```

**NOTES**: this code is from [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/src/lib/multipageloader.cc#L344) and `postData` is a QByteArray.

However, `Qt` 5 does not have the `addQueryItem()` function anymore. How do you port this code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to ensure compatibility with `Qt` 4, add the following lines at the top of your file:

```
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
#   include <QUrlQuery>
#endif
```

This means that `QUrlQuery` will only be `#include`d if you are compiling against `Qt` 5.0.0 or greater.

Then add the following line above the code specified in the question:

```
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
```

and then insert this code below the code specified in the question:

```
#else
    QUrlQuery q;
    foreach (const settings::PostItem & pi, settings.post)
        q.addQueryItem(pi.name, pi.value);
    postData = q.query(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8();
#endif
```

**NOTE**: `toUtf8()` is used because `postData` is a `QByteArray` and `query()` returns a `QString`. `toAscii()` was deprecated in `Qt` 5, but UTF-8 is a subset of ASCII with Unicode characters only when necessary.

**EDIT**: In the case you want to use a real `QUrl` that has a URL portion, add this:

```
 QUrl url;
 url.setQuery(q);
```

Comment: How does this change if `url` already has a partial query that I'd like to add to? I don't see a way to append to the existing query in a `QUrl`.

Comment: I realized right after I posted that you can initialize the `QUrlQuery` with the existing url to avoid overwriting existing queries, like this: `QUrlQuery q(url); q.addQuery(…); url.setQuery(q);`