# QNetworkAccessManager returning empty results

Tags: qt, httpclient, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest, qnetworkreply

I am struggling with qnetworkaccessmanager for quite sometime. I googled a lot, but I donot find a solution for this.

I am creating a client using qaccessmanager to talk with a rest server. QNetworkReply is not returning any results. The server is working properly but the client is not returning results. On top of that the server gets called 3 times and sometimes the server is crashing. Hope some one can figure out what is going wrong. I am attaching the client code.

I tried different approches like connecting finished signal of networkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply e.t.c. But all of them ends up in giving the same error "Connection Closed" or the readAll bytearray being empty.

```
void RestClientCore::ConnectToServer()
{
   m_NetworkManager  = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    QUrl url("http://localhost");
    url.setPort(5432);
    QByteArray postData;
     postData.append("/?userid=user");
     postData.append("&site=site");
    QNetworkReply *reply = m_NetworkManager->post(request,postData);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onRequestCompleted()));
}

void RestClientCore::onRequestCompleted() {

  QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());
    if(reply->error())
    {
      qDebug() <<reply->bytesAvailable() << reply->errorString();
    }
    else
    {
      qDebug() << reply->readAll();
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
}

void RestClientCore::slotReadyRead()
{
   QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());
   qDebug() << reply->readAll();
}
```

Thanks in advance
Regards
Rejo

Comment: Code creating request is missing.

Comment: [Example for adding parameters to a POST request](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18439557/2595147)

Comment: dear firescanner sorry to reply late. What is code creating request?

Comment: dear jbh. I used that code before and it has the same result as this one.

Comment: Where in your code do you create request that you pass to m_NetworkManager->post(request,postData);